# php UPDATE doesn't work

Tags: php, html, mysqli

My php code UPDATE code doesn't work. There are no error messages it doesn't update. Here is the code:

```
 <?php require 'connections/connections.php'; ?>
 <?php
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION["UserIdent"])){
}else{
header('Location: login.php');  
}
?>
<?php
$User = $_SESSION["UserIdent"];
$result = $con->query("select * from user where UserID='$User'");
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

$_SESSION["FirstName"] = $row['Fname'];
$_SESSION["LastName"] = $row['Lname'];
$_SESSION["Username"] = $row['Username'];
$_SESSION["Email"] = $row['Email'];
$_SESSION["Password"] = $row['Password'];
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['UpdateUser'])){
    $UpdateFname = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $UpdateLname = $_POST['LastName'];
    $UpdateUsername = $_POST['Username'];
    $UpdateEmail = $_POST['Email'];
    $UpdatePassword = $_POST['Password'];
    $sql = $con->query("UPDATE user SET Fname = '{$UpdateFname}',
    Lname = '{$UpdateLname}',
    Email = '{$UpdateEmail}',
    Username = '{$UpdateUsername}',
    Password = '{$UpdatePassword}',
    where UserID= $User");


    header('Location: UpdateAccount.php');
}

?>
```

The HTML code is here:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link href="css/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="css/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>UpdateAccount</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="holder">
  <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="NavBar">
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="account.php">Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="Logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
   </div>
  <div id="Content"></div>
 <div id="ContentLeft"></div>

 <div id="ContentRight"><form> <h6>
<label for="FirstName">First Name:<br>
</label>
<input name="FirstName" type="text" required="required" 
class="StyleTxtField" id="FirstName" value="<?php echo 
 $_SESSION["FirstName"]; ?>">
</h6>
<h6>
<label for="LastName">Last Name:<br>
</label>
<input name="LastName" type="text" required="required" class="StyleTxtField"
id="LastName" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["LastName"]; ?>">
</h6>
<h6>
<label for="Username">Username:<br>
</label>
<input name="Username" type="text" class="StyleTxtField" id="Username" 
value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Username"]; ?>">
</h6>
<h6>
<label for="Email">Email:<br>
</label>
<input name="Email" type="text" required="required" class="StyleTxtField" 
 id="Email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Email"]; ?>"> 
 </h6>
<h6>
<label for="Password">Password:<br>
</label>
<input name="Password" type="password" class="StyleTxtField" id="Password"
  value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Password"]; ?>">
</h6>

<p>
<input name="UpdateUser" type="submit" class="StyleTxtField" id="UpdateUser"
  value="UpdateUser">
 </p>
 </form></div>
 <div id="Footer"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The Problem is that I can't figure out why it isn't updating...Any Help I would be grateful. There are no errors so it should work fine but it doesn't.I just learning Mysqli so any security issues I am not worried about yet, all I want is help on how to get this code to work.
Thanks!

Comment: Quite a few errors in your code. You need to check for errors here, and you're not doing that.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code there is no method defined in `<form>`

You are using `$_POST` super global for fetching values. So your form method must be post as like:

```
<form method="post">
```

**UPDATE 1**

As my other friend **Fred-ii** suggest please make sure you are using `session_start()` in other files aswell where you need the information from `$_SESSION` specially in this file where you redirect the user

```
UpdateAccount.php
```

**Most important issues:**

- why are you saving password in session? And if its simple text no any encrypted function than its another issue. You need to save password in encrypted format.
- you need to prevent your code from SQL Injection.
- one more issue identified by @fred-ii remove ending comma from this line

  Password = '{$UpdatePassword}',

**Side note:**

Always active your `error_reporting` on development side not on production. You will get all the errors and save your time.

Comment: There a few other things that you missed (one is a syntax error), plus we don't know if OP started the session in their second file.

Comment: @fred-ii hi friend. Yes u r always right. My bad. Try to update something.

Comment: `Password = '{$UpdatePassword}',` <<< trailing comma ;-)

Comment: @fred-ii  ohh serious one what a eagle eye

Comment: What is the meaning of ii brother? In yur username? @fred-ii

Comment: there's another "Fred", which isn't me, but "another" one on Stack answering

Comment: :) and I assuming there is something technical short code lol. @fred-ii

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on that....I will take a look at it.....this was supposed to be an account update page.